# How to assign a struct's char[] to a file's value without it being a pointer?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

The values of each node in my linked list are all now equal to 'temp' though I want them to remain separate. When 'temp' is assigned to "STOP" in the last iteration of the while(1) loop all the other values are printed out as being "STOP" as well.

```
//*******************
//*  GEORGE TANGEN  *
//*      HW 9       *
//*******************

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node{
   struct node *next;
   struct building *payload;
};

struct building{
    char *name;
    struct arc *list[];
};

struct arc{
    int weight;
    struct building *start;
    struct building *end;
};

int main(){

   struct node *head;
   struct node *trace;
   head = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
   head->payload = malloc( sizeof(struct building) );
   head->payload->name = "Head";

   int k;
   trace = head;
   for(k=0;k<10;k++){
      trace->next = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
      trace = trace->next;
      trace->payload = malloc( sizeof(struct building) );
      trace->payload->name = "hi";
   }

    FILE *f1;
    int i,j;
    char *op = {"hw9.data"};   
    f1 = fopen(op,"r");
    if(f1==NULL){
        printf("No File!");
        return 0;
    }
      trace = head;
      char temp[200];
      while(1){
         fscanf(f1, "%s", temp);
         if( (strcmp(temp, "STOP"))==0 ){
            break;
         }else{
            printf("INPUT: %s\n", temp);
            trace->payload->name = temp;
            printf("OUTPUT: %s\n", trace->payload->name);
            printf("HEAD: %s\n", head->payload->name);
            trace = trace->next;
         }
         printf("%s\n\n", temp);

      }

      trace = head;
      for(k = 0; k<10;k++){
         printf("OUTPUT: %s\n", trace->payload->name);
         trace = trace->next;
      }


   fclose(f1);

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of array `temp` is overridden each time you call `fscanf` on it, there are two ways to this.

First, define payload to hold an array of chars, not just a pointer

```
struct node{
    struct node *next;
    struct building *payload;
};

struct building{
    char name[256];
    struct arc *list[];
};

// trace->payload->name = temp; do not assign here, copy the string
strcpy(trace->payload->name, temp);
```

Second, leave the struct unchanged, instead, make a new copy of the temp:

```
// trace->payload->name = temp; do not assign here, copy the string
trace->payload->name = strdup(temp);
```